generate random C maj diatonic notes in a range using music21
The code below generates notes between pitch 60 and 80 , but it also has non diatonic notes (like sharps and flats) in the midi file. How can i omit these from generating?
from music21 import stream, note, pitch, duration
import random

def generate_diatonic_notes(num_notes, min_pitch=60, max_pitch=80):
    s = stream.Stream()
    diatonic_notes = ['C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'A', 'B']

    for _ in range(num_notes):
        random_note_name = diatonic_notes[random.randint(0, 6)]
        n = note.Note()
        n.name = random_note_name
        print(n.pitch)
        n.duration = duration.Duration('eighth') 
        n.pitch.midi = random.randint(min_pitch, max_pitch)  <----- possible problem?
        s.append(n)
    return s

diatonic_notes_stream = generate_diatonic_notes(num_notes=20)


In case someone might be interested , i used following code to fix it
myScale = scale.ConcreteScale(pitches=['C','D','E','F','G','A','B'])
notes_in_scale = myScale.getPitches(low, high)

and then got a random note from notes_in_scale
a range can be setting spanning multiple octaves
